# How to use itertools to pass the returned values from one function to another?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list being returned as

```
[('10.12.250.29', 'pdx02-he-trial-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-e7775a10'), ('10.12.32.22', 'pdx02-cloud-prod-ansible01 Clone ', 'us-west-2b', 'vol-b0607d70'), ('10.12.0.20', 'pdx02-cloud-trial/dev-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-b32e5c46'), ('10.12.250.7', 'pdx02-he-prod-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-fd94400b'), ('10.12.250.4', 'pdx02-he-dev-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-ee6abf18'), ('10.12.32.16', 'pdx02-cloud-prod-ansible', 'us-west-2b', 'vol-ae49adbb'), ('10.121.15.22', 'ansible-classic', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-f893c20d'), ('10.17.15.145', 'pdx01-ms-dev-ansible', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-e2d45515'), ('10.21.32.27', 'fra01-cloud-prod-ansible', 'eu-central-1b', 'vol-5f86f5bd'), ('10.21.250.13', 'fra01-he-trial-ansible01', 'eu-central-1a', 'vol-f9e7d220'), ('10.21.250.27', 'fra01-he-dev-ansible01', 'eu-central-1a', 'vol-f6e3fa2f'), ('10.21.0.9', 'fra01-cloud-dev-ansible01', 'eu-central-1a', 'vol-98104671'), ('10.21.250.5', 'fra01-he-prod-ansible01', 'eu-central-1a', 'vol-809b8259'), ('10.31.250.26', 'sin01-he-dev-ansible01', 'ap-southeast-1a', 'vol-86443940'), ('10.31.250.19', 'sin01-he-prod-ansible01', 'ap-southeast-1a', 'vol-bebcc178'), ('10.31.32.12', 'sin01-cloud-prod-ansible01', 'ap-southeast-1b', 'vol-01409de9'), ('10.31.250.27', 'sin01-he-trial-ansible01', 'ap-southeast-1a', 'vol-f6cdc631'), ('10.31.0.18', 'sin01-cloud-dev-ansible01', 'ap-southeast-1a', 'vol-3c0aac28')]
```

this is basically:

```
<IP_ADDRESS> , <AWS_TAG_NAME> , <REGION> , <VOLUME>
```

now I passed it to another method where I need to extract each value and store it individually so I used `itertools` from `__main__` :

```
data = list(itertools.chain(*ansible_box_info))
print "-----------------"
print data
#mapping = {i[0]: [i[1], i[2]] for i in data}
print "Now Calling the Snapshot Creater!"
call_snapshot_creater(data)

def call_snapshot_creater(passed_data):
    ip_address = ','.join(list(itertools.chain(*[[j[0] for j in i] for i in data])))
    tags_descrip = list(itertools.chain(*[[j[1] for j in i] for i in data]))
    regions_az = list(itertools.chain(*[[j[2] for j in i] for i in data]))
    volume_id = list(itertools.chain(*[[j[3] for j in i] for i in data]))
```

This breaks the above list and picks just the first letter of everything , i.e the ip_address prints :

```
1,p,u,v,1,p,u,v,1,p,u,v,1,p,u,v,1,p,u,v,1,p,u,v,1,a,u,v,1,p,u,v,1,f,e,v,1,f,e,v,1,f,e,v,1,f,e,v,1,f,e,v,1,s,a,v,1,s,a,v,1,s,a,v,1,s,a,v,1,s,a,v
```

instead of 10.12.250.29 , 10.12.32.22 .................. 
and same for others

how to use the iterators to break this correctly ?

I am trying to create snapshots by passing these values to my snapshot creator :

```
def call_snapshot_creater(passed_data):
    ip_address = ','.join(list(itertools.chain(*[[j[0] for j in i] for i in data])))
    tags_descrip = list(itertools.chain(*[[j[1] for j in i] for i in data]))
    regions_az = list(itertools.chain(*[[j[2] for j in i] for i in data]))
    volume_id = list(itertools.chain(*[[j[3] for j in i] for i in data]))

    regions = ['us-west-2', 'eu-central-1', 'ap-southeast-1']

    for region in regions:
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region, aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY, )
        print "Snapshot Creation For Ansible -> ",ip_address," initiated , tag = ", tags_descrip ,"region : ", regions_az
        print "Snapshot will be created with -> Name : ",tags_descrip
        snapshot = ec2.create_snapshot(VolumeId=volume_id, Description=tags_descrip)
        print snapshot.id
        print "Snapshot is being created for Ansible box ", tags_descrip ,"with snapshot id :",snapshot.id
        #slack.chat.post_message(slack_channel,"Creating Snapshot for The volume"+ str(snapshot.id),username='Ansible_box_snapshot_bot')
        snapshot.load()
        while snapshot.state != 'completed':
            print "The Snapshot :", snapshot.id , "for Ansible box named : ", tags_descrip  ,"is currently in :",snapshot.state," state"
            time.sleep(30)
            snapshot.load()
            print snapshot.progress
        else:
            print "Snapshot ",snapshot.id, "for Ansible box ", tags_descrip , "is now Ready!! Final state ->",snapshot.state
```

Comment: Once you `chain`, your list of tuples gets flattened. Is this the behavior you intended? And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I think you want to use `[i[0] for i in data]`, `[i[1] for i in data]`, ... and that's it.

Comment: You are currently going through all the tuples, and select the first character of each string there, and pass that to `itertools.chain`, this is the reason for the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Updated the code, i am trying to pass these values to the snapshot creator function

Comment: @CodingLambdas : em , can u see my updated code.. how to update my code according to your suggestion here? also i created the `chain` in my `__main__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `[[j[0] for j in i] for i in data]` you are going through the list, and calculate `[j[0] for j in i]`, where `i` is the current tuple. So you iterate through the tuple, where `j` is the current string, and you get the first character of that string.

What you want however, is only the first item of the tuple. This means that you don't even need `itertools.chain`: Do it with `[i[0] for i in data]`. This gets the first element of each tuple, and yields the expected output.

So here is the changed code:

```py
ip_address = ','.join(i[0] for i in data)  # you can use an iterator here
tags_descrip = ','.join(i[1] for i in data)
regions_az = ','.join(i[2] for i in data)
volume_id = ','.join(i[3] for i in data)
```

This can, however, all be done in one line:

```
ip_address, tags_descrip, regions_az, volume_id = (','.join(j[i] for j in data) for i in range(4))
```

Another possibility would be following: (Here you only iterate over `data` once, but it isn't that readable)

```
ip_address, tags_descrip, regions_az, volume_id = map(','.join, zip(*data))
```

Here is how the second one works (I think the first one is self explanatory):

You pass following tuples to `zip`:

```
IP, ... from the first tuple
IP, ... from the second tuple
   .
   .
   .
```

So all the different fields are aligned. `zip` gives you an iterator, that returns the tuple containing the first items of each list, then a tuple containing the second items, and so on. So if you would call `list(zip(*data))`, you would have a list with for entries: All the IP's, and so on.

I would choose the first option over the second one, because the first one is a whole lot more readable, but if you really care for performance (but you wouldn't use Python in this case, I suppose), the second one is the way to go.

I hope I could help,

CodenameLambda

Comment: Okay, i get it. Also do you think i will be able to pass these i intended too ?  You see the snapshot creator method?

Comment: @Kittystone What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to create the snapshots by passing the volume id and tag names as descriptions , also i tried your code it says :

Comment: `  File "ebs_snapshot.py", line 71, in <module>
    call_snapshot_creater(ansible_box_info)
  File "ebs_snapshot.py", line 40, in call_snapshot_creater
    ip_address = ','.join(i[0] for i in data)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found`

Comment: In the code in your question, you don't convert any of the other values to strings, only the ip list. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I need to pass these values to the code below, please see the code i mentioned

Comment: @Kittystone just replace the `ip_address = ...` part with my code. This should theoretically work without any problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116558/discussion-between-kittystone-and-codinglambdas).

Answer (score 2):

You are not using `chain` and *unpacking* correctly. All you are trying to do, can be done with `zip` and *unpacking* viz. `zip(*...)`:

```
>>> l = [('10.12.250.29', 'pdx02-he-trial-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-e7775a10'), ('10.12.32.22', 'pdx02-cloud-prod-ansible01 Clone ', 'us-west-2b', 'vol-b0607d70'), ('10.12.0.20', 'pdx02-cloud-trial/dev-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-b32e5c46'), ('10.12.250.7', 'pdx02-he-prod-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-fd94400b'), ('10.12.250.4', 'pdx02-he-dev-ansible01', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-ee6abf18'), ('10.12.32.16', 'pdx02-cloud-prod-ansible', 'us-west-2b', 'vol-ae49adbb'), ('10.121.15.22', 'ansible-classic', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-f893c20d'), ('10.17.15.145', 'pdx01-ms-dev-ansible', 'us-west-2a', 'vol-e2d45515')]
>>>
>>> data = zip(*l)
>>>
>>> ip_address = ','.join(next(data))
>>> ip_address
'10.12.250.29,10.12.32.22,10.12.0.20,10.12.250.7,10.12.250.4,10.12.32.16,10.121.15.22,10.17.15.145'
>>>
>>> tags_descrip = ','.join(next(data))
>>> tags_descrip
'pdx02-he-trial-ansible01,pdx02-cloud-prod-ansible01 Clone ,pdx02-cloud-trial/dev-ansible01,pdx02-he-prod-ansible01,pdx02-he-dev-ansible01,pdx02-cloud-prod-ansible,ansible-classic,pdx01-ms-dev-ansible'
>>>
>>> regions_az = ','.join(next(data))
>>> regions_az
'us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2a,us-west-2a,us-west-2a,us-west-2b,us-west-2a,us-west-2a'
>>>
>>> volume_id = ','.join(next(data))
>>> volume_id
'vol-e7775a10,vol-b0607d70,vol-b32e5c46,vol-fd94400b,vol-ee6abf18,vol-ae49adbb,vol-f893c20d,vol-e2d45515'
```

Comment: oh , okay.. so i can ditch itertools i guess and just use this way.. , also do u think i will be able to pass these value one by one to the snapshot creator function ?

Comment: @Kittystone It should work as long as your code can take these parameters and use them for what you intend

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I think that you shouldn't call `list(zip(*l))`, it should be faster to just unpack them directly from `zip`: `ip_address, tags_descrip, regions_az, volume_id = (','.join(i) for i in zip(*l))`. One reason for that one is: Don't repeat yourself.

Comment: @CodingLambdas You can also do that, but the one liner is less readable when you're having 4 or more items after unpacking the *RHS*

Comment: @MosesKoledoye You could use `next(data)` instead of accessing it by the index, then you would use `data = zip(*l)`. Basically the same thing.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye And you could use `data = map(','.join, zip(*l))`, then you just use `ip_address = next(data)`.

Comment: @CodingLambdas Thanks, the `next` version is better

Comment: Guys,  I am still at the same issue i tried both of you guys answer and it says `ip_address = ','.join(data[0])
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found` , also please have a look at the code which i have pasted which takes these values as input

Comment: @MosesKoledoye No problem.

Comment: @Kittystone I tried it with the input you provided, and it works. Are all the items in the tuples strings? Because if they aren't, then you get a `TypeError`, because python doesn't convert them implicitly.